# Why waiting an async method that internally awaits a completed task, produces unexpected output?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

I have the following code block:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Task task = ExampleTaskAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Method invoked");
        task.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("main finished");
    }
    static async Task ExampleTaskAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started await");
        await Task.FromResult(189);
        Console.WriteLine("During await");
        await Task.Delay(867);
        Console.WriteLine("completed await");
    }
}
```

When I run this code block, it always produces the following output:

```
Started await
During await
Method invoked
completed await
main finished
```

I was expecting the following output:

```
Started await
Method invoked
During await
completed await
main finished
```

Could you explain why the `"During await"` appears before the `"Method invoked"`?

Comment: I recommend you read my [async intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), which explains this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `Task task = ExampleTaskAsync();` that method starts running synchronously until it hits the first time there is a *real* Task to wait for. That is why you see "Started await" first.

Next issue is that `await Task.FromResult(189);` doesn't really wait: FromResult (and Task.CompletedTask) immediately return a *completed* task so the method doesn't need to wait and **continues synchronously**. That's why you also see "During await".

Next is a `await Task.Delay(867);` which immediately returns an imcomplete Task, which *does* cause the method to return an incomplete task. So you don't yet get to "completed await", but see "Method invoked".

When the delay finishes, the ExampleTaskAsync method continues and prints "completed await". Then the Task belonging to this method is complete and the Wait in the Main is over so you see the final "main finished".

---

Note that your Main method should also be async (`async Task Main()`), so you can `await task`, instead of using Wait() which may cause a deadlock.

Comment: *"Note that your Main method should also be async (async Task Main()), so you can await task."* -- This is not really needed. As long as there is no synchronization context installed, there is no risk of a deadlock. The `async Task Main` is just syntactic sugar for doing a synchronous blocking `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If your are asking why is there a different between

#### Observed

```
...
During await
Method invoked
...
```

#### Expected

```
...
Method invoked
During await
...
```

then the answer is because `await Task.FromResult(189);` always finishes synchronously.

There is no point to suspend the execution of `ExampleTaskAsync` and give back the control to the caller.

If you copy-paste the code to [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7NAExAGoAfAAQCYAGAWAChqBGRimgAguYFYBuRoKZIOGAIYBnANYcAvBwCiCMQFsADgBsYFJAEEJATzxgAFAEoBTZgE4TAIgCyMDAAsIhDgEs8ANwhSYQjsLRnFpADoAdTFPDHNLbls7FRi8DgAzb08JF0DgyzZmEQoADi4RJVVNbT1DY3NGAG9GDlauG3sAZXEoDECua3yWtoprcvCAMSgIFQAlGAkcDTjmEusQhjb2pIARHChvAHMBoc2RsZ1wnZgNMQMTEqQAdg2txPtIdS0+j1HTgF8gA==) you can see how the execution flow is changing during the application execution.

[image: sharplab]

I also suggest to examine [the generated async state machine's code](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQCYAGAWACgiBGC/YgAnyoFYBuCjypegFwEMAzgGt6AXnoBRBHwC2ABwA2MfEgCCAgJ4A7MAAoAlO0pUAnLoBEAWRg8AFhAz0AlloBuEITAznDFfsIA6AHU+Jx4DIyYzcxlQrXoAMxcnAVsvHyNaKm58AA5GbilZRWU1TR0DCgBvCno6xlMLAGV+KB4vRhMM2vr8EwKAgDEoCBkAJRgBAFcFcKpck19yeobogBEpqBcAc07u5d7+lQC1mAU+DV1cpAB2JZWoi0h5JXbHPv2AXyA===).

[image: async state machine]